# Fetching Twitter Feed with JSON and JQuery - Automatically Refresh?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, refresh

I am working on a script which will "fetch" the latest tweets from the Twitter API, and then display them as HTML on my page using JQuery.

I'm new to JQuery, so if someone could point me in the direction of the necessary function on the JQuery site I would be most grateful.

I currently have built the following script:

```
<!-- Use the Google jQuery CDN for lib support -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Setup and fetch the JSON data -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=@req';
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
<!-- Iterate the file -->
        $.each(json.results,function(i,tweet){
           $("#results").append('<p><img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+'" widt="48" height="48" />'+tweet.text+'</p>');
$("#results").slideDown("slow");
        });
                    });
});
</script>
<!-- Output the file into the DIV -->
<div id="results"></div>
```

The script is working fine, however I would now like to incorporate some form of automatic refresh of the content. I.e "re-fetch" the feed every x minutes.

From what I understand I need to replace .append with .html in order that the content is removed from the page before reload, however does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way of actually getting the content to refresh? I have found may articles expressing concerns over browser memory leaks etc, and don't want to head down the wrong path.

I look forward to you responses, and thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    function getTweets() {
        var url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=@req';
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){

            //setup an array to buffer output
            var output = [];

            //a for loop will perform faster when setup like this
            for (var i = 0, len = json.results.length; i < len; i++) {

               //instead of appending each result, add each to the buffer array
               output.push('<p><img src="' + json.results[i].profile_image_url + '" widt="48" height="48" />' + json.results[i].text + '</p>');
            }

            //now select the #results element only once and append all the output at once, then slide it into view
            $("#results").html(output.join('')).slideDown('slow');
        });
    }

    //set an interval to run the getTweets function (30,000 ms is 5 minutes), you can cancel the interval by calling clearInterval(timer);
    var timer = setInterval(getTweets, 30000);

    //run the getTweets function on document.ready
    getTweets();

});
```

Here is some good documentation for `window.setInterval()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

Comment: To make sure that you doesn't stack the calls, in case the server is responding slowly, I guess it would be better to use setTimeout, and then set a new timeout from inside getTweets to call itself again in X seconds - after the AJAX call has complete. With 50 seconds I guess you would be alright with setInterval as well, but if he wants to run it every 10 seconds, there is a risk that the AJAX-calls will queue up.

Comment: Thank you Jasper and @Christofer Eliasson for your prompt replies.
I have implemented your code Jasper and that is exactly what I am looking to do with regards to the refresh, so thanks for that. As mentioned in my initial post I am now looking to ensure that content is removed upon reload. I have replaced .append with .html which appears to do the trick, however please could you confirm this IS actually removing the content prior to reload, and not doing something else entirely.

Comment: Christofer, I will be looking to refresh the content around every 60 seconds, however what would be the worst case scenario should I choose to decrease the time limit?

Comment: @user1055774 `.html(<CODE>)` is the same thing as `.empty().append(<CODE>)`.

Comment: @user1055774 When you use setInterval, the function will be run again, no matter if the previous call to the function is still executing - in case the Twitter API get slow, and you don't get a response within your minute interval, you will start to stack AJAX-requests. I say either you use setTimeout instead, as described in my previous comment, or you change .getJSON() to use the .ajax() method instead, and specify the timeout-option to be shorter than your interval. Either way, you avoid getting a queue of AJAX-requests.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson Please can you confirm this syntax is correct in place of setInterval: var timer = setTimeout(getTweets(), 1000); - Thanks.

Comment: @user1055774 `var timer = setTimeout(getTweets, 1000);` -- notice the `()` are removed from the function name. You can also use `var timer = setTimeout(function () { getTweets(); }, 1000);`

Answer (score 3):

Why do people always want to use a massive library like jQuery for the most basic things?

Javascript's [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) can do this for you.